# LinkedIn iOS integration

Tags: iphone, ios, social-networking, linkedin-api

I am integrating `Linked-in` in my iOS application to `Login` my app.it works fine for me ..it login successfully when i enter the credentials in the app and enters in the app successfully ....but when i `logout` and `login` again it ask for the `Access`-->`allow access` button  without asking the credientials but I want `allow access` page should not come on the next login ...means after `logout` when again i click on the ``` linkedin``login ```...it should directly access to the app ..should not ask for image 2..

[image]

**image 2 which comes on the second time `login`..which i dont want to come**
.

[image]

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
 {

     NSMutableArray *toolbarButtons = [toolBar.items mutableCopy];
     // toolbarItems = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:toolbar.items]
     // This is how you remove the button from the toolbar and animate it
     // This is how you add the button to the toolbar and animate it

    if (!firstTime1||![loginView canGoBack]) 
    {
        [toolbarButtons removeObject:backButton];
        [toolBar setItems:toolbarButtons animated:YES];
        firstTime1=YES;
    }

NSURL *url = request.URL;
NSString *urlString = url.absoluteString;

    BOOL requestForCallbackURL = ([urlString rangeOfString:[LinkedIn linked].linkedInCallbackURL].location != NSNotFound);
    if ( requestForCallbackURL )
    {
        BOOL userAllowedAccess = ([urlString rangeOfString:@"user_refused"].location == NSNotFound);
        if ( userAllowedAccess )
        {
            if ([self logoutPreviousSession])
            {
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:1 forKey:@"SuccessfulLogin"];
                [DelegateClass magazine]._loggedThrough=@"LinkedIn";
                [[LinkedIn linked].requestToken setVerifierWithUrl:url];
                [[LinkedIn linked] accessTokenFromProvider];
            }

        }
        else
        {

             [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }
    }
return YES;
 }
```

Comment: you are clear token info when you are logout

Comment: look this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PXuu3t3pIe4